# Unrecognized name: employees at [9:8]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, inner-join

This is giving me an unrecognized name error. Why?

```
SELECT 
    employees.name AS employee_name,
    employees.role AS employee_role,
    departments.name AS department_name
FROM 
    `strange-calling-318804.employee_data.Employees`
    JOIN 
    `strange-calling-318804.employee_data.departments` 
    ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

> ```
> Unrecognized name: employees at [9:8]
> ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WeT9.png)

Comment: you are missing aliases `employees` and `departments` after full table references! you use them in ON clause but you missed to define them!

Comment: Debugging questions require a [mre].  Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. [ask] [Help] Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish.

Comment: Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. For compiler errors chop code down until as small as possible with that error then chop down until OK & add back what caused the error. (Debugging basic.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing aliases `employees` and `departments` after full table references! you use them in ON clause but you missed to define them!

```
SELECT 
    employees.name AS employee_name,
    employees.role AS employee_role,
    departments.name AS department_name
FROM 
    `strange-calling-318804.employee_data.Employees` as employees
    JOIN 
    `strange-calling-318804.employee_data.departments` as departments 
    ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had same challenge an its solved using your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your tables aliases.  I would recommend abbreviations for the table names:

```
SELECT e.name AS employee_name, e.role AS employee_role,
       d.name AS department_name
FROM `strange-calling-318804.employee_data.Employees` e JOIN
     `strange-calling-318804.employee_data.departments` d 
     ON e.department_id = d.department_id;
```