# Unrecognizable table name in Big Query while using JOINS

Tags: join, google-bigquery

[image]

Hi,
I am trying to use the INNER JOIN clause on Big Query to join rows from tables titled employees and departments. But it's not recognizing the table name employees. What am I doing wrong here?

I tried adding the dataset name before the table names but it didn't work.

Comment: you can check here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68898855/unrecognized-name-employees-at-98

Answer (score 1):

Add an alias on each table and it should work :

- my-project-new-gdac.employee_data.employees employees
- my-project-new-gdac.employee_data.departments departments