# Table name is being shown as Unrecognised Name in INNER JOIN clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, inner-join

I'm learning SQL and came across an example of INNER JOIN with the following query :

```
SELECT
    employees.name AS employee_name,
    employees.role AS employee_role,
    departments.name AS department_name
FROM 
    `inbound-sight-376714.employee_data.employees`
INNER JOIN
    `inbound-sight-376714.employee_data.departments`
      ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

When running this query, I get an error saying employees of `employees.department_id` in the `ON` clause is an unrecognized name.

I tried putting the full address of the column by including the project and the dataset name on the both sides of the `ON` clause. Also tried removing employees. and departments. from the ON clause -
neither worked.

Comment: Please add the columns of the employee and department tables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unrecognized name: employees at \[9:8\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68898855/unrecognized-name-employees-at-98)